# Multiple pages with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML that currently produces a single page. Depending on which "product" is selected, I'd like to use the "Multiple Page" feature, inserted with javascript.

Here is some sample code:

```
<div id="products">

  <div id="product-1" class="product">
    <a href="/product/marco" title="View marco" class="product-a">
      <span class="stilt"></span>
      <div class="product-info"><h3 class="product-title"><span>marco</span></h3><p class="product-price"><span><span class="currency_sign">€</span>23.00</span></p></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="product-2" class="product">
    <a href="/product/la-regola-dell-amico" title="View la regola dell'amico" class="product-a">
      <span class="stilt"></span>
      <div class="product-info"><h3 class="product-title"><span>la regola dell'amico</span></h3><p class="product-price"><span><span class="currency_sign">€</span>22.00</span></p></div>
    </a>
  </div>
.
.
.
</div>
```

I want to split the "products" div into multiple pages for the inner div with id "product-9", for example. How do I do that?

**EDIT**
It may not be clear, i have a lot of products and i want to display 9 product per page

Comment: do you use prototype-js, jquery or moo-tools?

Comment: Does this mean you want to show the products in blocks of 9 produces? I.e. show product 1 to 9, then 10 to 18, etc? Your question is not very clear to me.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, i want to split my div every 9 products

Comment: It may be prudent to create an AJAX service to load up batches of pages of products if there is a huge amount of them. jQuery would be a good option to achieve this. That way your DOM stays small and you're loading content on the fly rather than all at once.

Comment: @JeffWatkins i can't, i have to add functionalities to a pre-built e-commerce script, i can't create pages, i only can add some javascript to add functionalities that the shop doesn't have, the homepage contains all products in the store and i need to split them up in different pages

Comment: Well doing what you requested is pretty simple in jQuery. You could just use a selector $("#product-" + (pageOffset + x)) where x is a loop from 0-8 and show on those divs, hiding the previous ones in a similar fashion (you can use .toggle on elements to do this). Not a lot of code.

Comment: @JeffWatkins Can you give me an example? i'm not very familiar with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a VERY basic example using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/LZuC6/)

The crux is here:

```
function togglePage(page)
{
    for (var i = 1 ; i < pageSize  + 1; i++)
    {
        $("#product-" + ((page * pageSize) + i)).toggle();

    }
}
```

You can use more complex selectors to do this in less code, but I've kept it simple for non jQuery users to be able to read.

Basically, I'm calculating the items to show each time based on the page size. I've limited it to two for simplicity's sake. The CSS has display:none on it to hide by default.

There is no upper-bound checking on the page number, but it wouldn't be hugely difficult to create some.

Comment: I was looking if this is the best way to do that or if there are other better ways before accepting the answer